# perl : copy line with specific string and replace strings in copied line

Tags: perl

Here is my question. lets say i have one file, lets say a.txt with contents as follow:

```
a aa aaa
b bb bbb
c cc ccc
b bb bbb
d dd ddd
```

then i want to find all lines (one by one) having string lets say "bb" then copy this line and replace the string "bb" with "ee" in newly copied/duplicated line.
so my final output i.e. contents of file a.txt, will be as follow:

```
 a aa aaa
 b bb bbb
 b ee bbb
 c cc ccc
 b bb bbb
 b ee bbb
 d dd ddd
```

Can anybody help me with perl command for this? or is there any better option than perl to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? I see someone has already given you an answer, but Stack Overflow isn't really about people writing code for you, it's for us to help you fix specific problems in your own code.

Comment: I tried the command like "perl -pe 'print if /bb/' a.txt" but this was just giving me copied line so l was looking for command to replace the string in copied line also. Thanks to @sean for his help

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include the code.  @DaveCross is right in that without it, your question is likely incomplete and off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward Perl program; just read lines, match them with whatever you're searching for, and substitute text as necessary.

Run this as `perl script.pl < a.txt`:

```
while (<>) {
    print;
    if (m/bb/) {
        s/bb/ee/g;
        print;
    }
}
```

Note that if you only want to substitute whole words (instead of things that just *contain* `bb`), you'll need to adjust the regexes with `\b` word boundaries accordingly:

```
while (<>) {
    print;
    if (m/\bbb\b/) {
        s/\bbb\b/ee/g;
        print;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:  Since the request was specifically for a "perl command for this," here's a one-liner that embeds the script directly:

```
perl -n -e 'print; if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/\bbb\b/ee/g; print; }' < a.txt
```

Comment: I think you need to read the question more carefully.

Comment: @Borodin: The output of my second script perfectly matches his desired output, byte-for-byte. What do you think was missed?

Comment: My apologies: I misread your code.

Comment: @SeanWerkema This one liner from edit section is giving me output as expected but its not making these changes in place i.e. in file itself. Can we modify this command so that current output of this one liner perl command will be contents of file (a.txt). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pipe the output to a new file (`> b.txt`), and copy the new file over top of the old one (`cp b.txt a.txt`).

Comment: Thanks @SeanWerkema, given one liner as follow works for me: perl -n -e 'print; if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/\bbb\b/ee/g; print; }' a.txt > c.txt